# An odd output about a struct in C

Tags: c, struct

I tried a simple struct.

```
#include<stdio.h>
struct test
{ 
  int i; 
  int j; 
}; 
int main() 
{ 
  struct test t; 
  t.i=1; 
  t.j=2; 
  printf("t:%d, i:%d, j:%d\n", t, t.i, t.j); 
}
```

the output is incorrect as:

```
"t:1, i:2, j:1 "
```

if I change the printf sentence to

```
printf("i:%d, j:%d\n", t.i, t.j);
```

the output is correct:

```
"i:1, j:2"
```

why the first one cannot print the correct output? Am I missing something here?
I'm using gcc on ubuntu.
Thanks.

Comment: Trying to print "t" with a %d surely must lead to a compiler warning. It's best not to ignore them, they are *trying* to tell you something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern you give `printf()` tells it how it should read the sequence of parameters. You tell `printf()` to read a `%d` but gives it a `struct test` instead of an `int`. This messes the whole thing because `struct test` is dumped in the stack and it takes a lot more space than an `int` would.

`printf()` patterns can only support primitives and pointers to null-terminated strings as parameters. It doesn't have the ability to print a `struct`.

Comment: Thanks. this way it make sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

```
printf("t:%d, i:%d, j:%d\n", t, t.i, t.j);
```

The first variable on this line, t, is a structure, and you attempted to output it as a digit. 
Since structures have no values of their own, but contain variables instead, referring to this structure t as having some sort of integer value resulted in unexpected results.

Comment: No, I'm just trying to see what comes out. Anyway, I assume even I try to print a struct as a integer, it shouldn't affect the out put for the following struct member. so I'm just confused.

Comment: Well you did! The wrong thing comes out. When you said "struct test t;" inside int main(), you created a sort of sub structure. Since structures have no values of their own, but contain variables instead, referring to this structure t as having some sort of integer value resulted in unexpected results.

Answer (score 0):

When printing the struct, you are actually printing the first 2 ints. Then t.i is printed as the last int. then t.j is ignored. This happens because your struct consists of 2 int's that are placed in memory in that order.